# Xcode: why does Xcode shows an image bigger then AS-IS?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, ios10, google-maps-sdk-ios

Why does Xcode shows a image bigger then AS-IS?

http://users.telenet.be/thomazz/ScreenShot4.png

http://users.telenet.be/thomazz/ScreenShot3.png

Scenario:

1. I got an image.
2. I resize this UIImage.
3. I export the resized UIImage.
4. I comment out my resize code.
5. I import the resized image in Xcode.
6. problem 1: Xcode shows the image twice as big as normal.
7. problem 2: when I run my app with the exported-resized image, it is twice as big.

view screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

This totally depends on your frame of your UIImageView and not its dimensions.

So if you have an 1024x1024 image and you place it in a 10x10 frame, it will render to 10x10 size and vice versa.

If you want it bigger, then make your UIImageView bigger

Edit: so it is a google maps icon

Set the resized image as marker icon ,i.e,

```
marker.icon = self.imageWithImage(image: UIImage(named: "imageName")!, scaledToSize: CGSize(width: 3.0, height: 3.0))
```

Add this function

```
func imageWithImage(image:UIImage, scaledToSize newSize:CGSize) -> UIImage{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0);
    image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height))
    let newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

Comment: I don't have a frame. I'm using the google-maps-ios-sdk. And what I do is: GMSMarker.icon = UIImage.

Comment: let marker = GMSMarker();
let image = UIImage(named: "marker_77.png")!;
marker.icon = image;

Comment: I edited my answer. please check it and inform me if it works

Comment: thnx, I'm sure your new code works, but what I want to avoid is this "return newImage". So what I do then is calling this: UIImagePNGRepresentation(resizedImage). And then using this exported image. so I don't have a "return **NEW** Image"

Answer (score 0):

Dear Mohammad Bashir Sidani, I have this code.
And this code works. but it creates a new UIImage.
Then I use UIImagePNGRepresentation(resizedImage) to export the image. 
I disable the code below to use the "programmatically-resized image".
this new resized image is blown up by Xcode... :(

```html
extension UIImage {
    func resizeImage(_ dimension: CGFloat, opaque: Bool, contentMode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) -> UIImage {
        var width: CGFloat
        var height: CGFloat
        var newImage: UIImage
        
        let size = self.size
        let aspectRatio =  size.width/size.height
        
        switch contentMode {
        case .scaleAspectFit:
            if aspectRatio > 1 {                            // Landscape image
                width = dimension
                height = dimension / aspectRatio
            } else {                                        // Portrait image
                height = dimension
                width = dimension * aspectRatio
            }
            
        default:
            fatalError("UIIMage.resizeToFit(): FATAL: Unimplemented ContentMode")
        }
        
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let renderFormat = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.default()
            renderFormat.opaque = opaque
            let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: width, height: height), format: renderFormat)
            newImage = renderer.image {
                (context) in
                self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
            }
        } else {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: width, height: height), opaque, 0)
            self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
            newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }
        
        return newImage
    }
}
```